# Can't get the WM_TOUCH messages in a Hook

Tags: c++, windows, api, touch, hook

I need to make my app Touch-Compliant, and that's why I dived in the Windows Touch API these days.

The Windows API is quite new for me, that's why I missed maybe something.

Here is my problem:
I've downloaded the Microsoft [Sample of a simple Gesture App](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsTouch). It works well, but the Gesture Feature is added processed in a WinProc that is bound on the HWND creation. The thing is that my "real"  application creates itself its HWND, and that's why I would like to use a hook to receive the WM_TOUCH messages.

I tried like this in a standalone app (no DLLs used like in my real app)

```
//Window Parameters (Can't be modified in my original App)
//------Automatically called by an external lib in my "real app"------------
ATOM BaseApp_RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc      = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra       = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra       = 0;
    wcex.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon            = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MTGEST));
    wcex.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName     = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MTGEST);
    wcex.lpszClassName    = (LPSTR)g_wszWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm          = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}    
//------/Automatically called by an external lib in my "real app"------------

//Create the Window of the Basic App
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    //------Automatically called by an external lib in my "real app"------------
    // (....)
    BaseApp_RegisterClass(hInstance);
    // (....)
    //------/Automatically called by an external lib in my "real app"------------

   //------This is what I can add to my "real app"------------
   //Register the Touch Window
   RegisterTouchWindow(hWnd, 0 );
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   unsigned long threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, 0);
    //Hook the SENT Messages
    SetWindowsHookEx(
        WH_GETMESSAGE,
        (HOOKPROC) HookTouchSENT,
        NULL,
        threadId);  

    //Hook the POSTED Messages
   SetWindowsHookEx(
       WH_CALLWNDPROC,
       (HOOKPROC) HookTouchPOSTED,
       NULL,
       threadId);

   //------/This is what I can add to my "real app"------------
}

//------Automatically called by an external lib in my "real app"------------
//Primary WinProc of the Window (Can't be modified in my original App)
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(message == WM_TOUCH)LogInConsole("Caught a WM_TOUCH in the Main WndProc\n");   //WM_TOUCH is ALWAYS caught here when touch the screen
    else if(message == WM_GESTURE)LogInConsole("Caught a WM_GESTURE in the Main WndProc\n");

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
//------/Automatically called by an external lib in my "real app"------------

//------This is what I can add to my "real app"------------
//Get the 'POSTED' Messages of the Window
LRESULT CALLBACK HookTouchPOSTED(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)  
{
    HWND hWnd = m_hwnd; 

    UINT message = ((PCWPSTRUCT)lParam)->message; 

    if(message == WM_TOUCH)LogInConsole("Caught a WM_TOUCH in HookTouchPOSTED\n");   //WM_TOUCH is NEVER caught here when touch the screen
    else if(message == WM_GESTURE)LogInConsole("Caught a WM_GESTURE in HookTouchPOSTED\n");   


    std::stringstream strStream; strStream<<"Received POSTED Message:"<<message<<", Hex:0x"<<std::hex<<((PCWPSTRUCT)lParam)->message<<std::endl;  //Receive the normals windows messages and although WM_GESTURENOTIFY
    LogInConsole(strStream.str());

    return CallNextHookEx(0,nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

//Get the 'SENT' Messages of the Window
LRESULT CALLBACK HookTouchSENT(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{

    HWND hWnd = m_hwnd; 

    UINT message = ((PCWPSTRUCT)lParam)->message; 

    if(message == WM_TOUCH)LogInConsole("Caught a WM_TOUCH in HookTouchPOSTED\n");   //WM_TOUCH is NEVER caught here when touch the screen
    else if(message == WM_GESTURE)LogInConsole("Caught a WM_GESTURE in HookTouchPOSTED\n");

    std::stringstream strStream; strStream<<"Received POSTED Message:"<<message<<", Hex:0x"<<std::hex<<((PCWPSTRUCT)lParam)->message<<std::endl;
    LogInConsole(strStream.str());

    return CallNextHookEx(0,nCode, wParam, lParam);
}    
//------/This is what I can add to my "real app"------------
```

My problem is that the WM_TOUCH Message never pass through the Hooks, but only in the WinProc. Indeed I only receive a WM_GESTURENOTIFY Message in the hooks, that notify that a gesture has started, but the following "WM_TOUCH" messages that should give the values are never caught...

Does anybody has had this problem before?

Thanx in advance for the help

Comment: Why not just modify the WndProc of your "real" app?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access on the WndProc of my "real" app. I use a piece of code that initiate itself the HWND,and declares  it's own WndProc.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I thought you wrote this app (you wrote 'my app'). If the window was created by an in-proc component you can subclass it.

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanx for the help ;)
Ok sorry for the confusion, I add some extra explications in comments, to show where are the pieces of codes that I can't change, and where are the pieces that I can.

Comment: Then subclass the window. A hook is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Thanx Raymond for the help. Subclassing was the solution!
So finally I removed all my hooks and made like this:

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    //------Automatically called by an external lib in my "real app"------------
    // (....)
    BaseApp_RegisterClass(hInstance);
    // (....)
    //------/Automatically called by an external lib in my "real app"------------



   //------This is what I can add to my "real app"------------
   //Register the Touch Window
   RegisterTouchWindow(hWnd, 0 );   //If called then receive WM_TOUCH messages. Else receive WM_GESTURE messages

   //----SUBCLASS THE WINDOW
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass;
    DWORD_PTR dwRefData;

   bool resultsc = SetWindowSubclass(
       hWnd,
       windowProcSubclass,
       uIdSubclass,
       dwRefData
       );
   if (resultsc) LogInConsole("Window Subclassed with success\n");
   //----/SUBCLASS THE WINDOW

   //------/This is what I can add to my "real app"------------
}

//------And the subclass Proc that now catches the WM_TOUCH and WM_GESTURE messages: ------------
LRESULT CALLBACK windowProcSubclass(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,  UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_TOUCH:
        LogInConsole("CATCH A WM_TOUCH!!\n");
        break;
    case WM_GESTURENOTIFY:
        LogInConsole("WM_GESTURENOTIFY!!\n");
        break;      
    case WM_GESTURE:
        LogInConsole("CATCH A WM_GESTURE!!\n");        
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: In windowProcSubclass() "return DefWindowProc(...)" should normally be "return DefSubclassProc(...)" - right now you are not calling the parent window's winproc